# how to write svg code to a file and save It in media folder in Django?

Tags: python, django, svg, barcode, weasyprint

I have a function that generates a barcode as svg code.
I need to display this svg in an HTML PDF template. but unfortunately inline svg doesn't work.

so as a workaround I need to write this code into a file and save it in the media folder so I can access it by  tag in the HTML PDF template.

Below is the function that generates the barcode:

```
def barcode_number(self):
  number = self.get_real_instance().number
  svg_code = generate('code39', str(number).zfill(20), pil=True)
  code = svg_code.decode("utf-8")
  ## here I want to write code into barcode.svg file 
  safe_html = mark_safe(svg_code)
  return safe_html
```

How can I write this code to a svg file and save it in '/media/uploads' ?

Thank you

Comment: why `inline svg doesn't work` ? What do you get? Maybe in template you should use `svg_code  | safe`. Or maybe you should use `base64` in `<img scr="image/svg;base64, ...">`

Comment: and if you want to write in file then use standard `open()`, `write()`, `close()`. But first check if module doesn't have function to save it.

Comment: I don't know what module you use but in [python-barcode]9https://pypi.org/project/python-barcode/) I see `generate(... output="filename")` which you can use to save it in file. There is also function `.save(...)`

Comment: Thanks furas it worked! i used output paramter in generate enerate('code39', number, output=file_name)